# What is the speed, reach and stagger of unarmed attacks in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to calculate the damage per second of unarmed attacks in Skyrim.  While it's easy to find information on the damage values, for instance on the [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unarmed_Combat), I haven't been able to find information on how fast you attack unarmed compared to other weapons.

1. How fast do characters make unarmed attacks?  Are there any effects/perks/modifiers that change unarmed attack speed?
2. What is the reach of unarmed?  [This page](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Combat#Reach_for_Unarmed_Combat) says  1.  The UESP Lycanthropy page says that normal unarmed reach is 96, while werewolves have unarmed reach 150.  I assume these numbers are in different units.  What are the real numbers?
3. What is the stagger multiplier for unarmed?

Comment: I don't have Skyrim installed right now, so I can't verify this, but have you tried going into the creation kit, and looking for the unarmed tab? All the other weapons in-game have damage, speed, and reach values you can look at, I imagine you could find unarmed as well.

Comment: There is an entry in the CK for unarmed, but it only applies to brawls, see [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/334g80/discovered_something_interesting_in_the_creation/).  If there are values for unarmed in the CK, they're somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I know the answer to 2 now.  [The Creation Kit](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Weapons) says the reach values listed for weapons are used in a formula fCombatDistance * NPCScale * WeaponReach.  The [UESP database](http://content3.uesp.net/oblivion/cs/cslist.php?game=sr&formid=0x00055640) suggests that the value for fCombatDistance for Skyrim is 141, and that the unarmed reach for vampire lords is the same as for werewolves, 150.  One-handed swords have WeaponReach 1 so actual reach of 141, so werewolves and vampire lords have slightly longer reach.  A dagger has 98.7 reach, slightly longer than the base unarmed reach for all of the PC races, 96.  These values are all in units, the fundamental measure of length in the game engine.

Comment: Do you mean 100, rather than 1?

Comment: I edited the observation about one-handed swords to clarify the difference between WeaponReach and actual reach.